# Code Analysis does not show CA1804 warning despite unused local string variable in C# (VS2010 Premium)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I've got the following code that does *not* produce an CA1804 warning (declared variable is never used) from code analysis (VS2010 Premium):

```
...
if( boolVariable )
{
    string errorText = "Bla Bla Bla"; // Never used
    ErrorProvider.SetError( SomeControl, "Some Warning" );
}
else
{
    string errorText = "Acme Acme Acme"; // Used below
    ErrorProvider.SetError( SomeControl, errorText );
}
...
```

When I remove the *ErrorProvider.SetError( ... )* lines, the CA1804 warning is shown, but why is this not the case in the code sample above?

(Btw: The code itself is not too great and just shown to illustrate my question.)

Any ideas what might be causing this behaviour? I guess this might be down to the fact that the IL code is optimised in a way that puts the declaration outside the **if**, which in turn would mean that the warning should indeed not show up in an example like the one above, but I'm not sure whether this is true.

Thanks in advance

G.

Comment: It probably shifts the `string errorText = ...` outside the `if` and fails to notice the difference between the two equally named variables. Does it continue to fail when you change the first `errorText` to `errorText2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be because of an optimization performed by the C# compiler.  In the generated IL, the variable declaration is hoisted out of the `if` block:

```
string errorText;
if (boolVariable)
{
    errorText = "Bla Bla Bla";
    this.ErrorProvider.SetError(this.SomeControl, "Some Warning");
}
else
{
    errorText = "Acme Acme Acme";
    this.ErrorProvider.SetError(this.SomeControl, errorText);
}
```

Removing only the second SetError call is actually sufficient to trigger CA1804.

BTW, the C# compiler should have issued a [CS0219](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kycwe2x.aspx) warning for this, which you apparently ignored.  I would very strongly recommend treating compiler warnings as errors if you're remotely interested in code quality, which you presumably are if you are running Code Analysis. Why add an additional screening tool before you take maximum advantage of the one you are already using?

Comment: Thank you, so my guessing was correct. Regarding your CS0219 advice - I cannot find such a warning in VS2010 with CA1804 being enabled in code analysis (warning level is generally set to 4 in our projects). Imho both warn about the same issue anyway ("...declares a variable, '...', of type '...', which is never used or is only assigned to ..." vs. "The variable '...' is assigned but its value never used."), or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're not seeing the compiler warning.  Is this particular project particularly not set for level 4 warnings even though most are?  Or perhaps this particular warning is disabled via project configuration or a `#pragma warning disable`?  As for the CS0219 and CA1804 warning about the same issue, their goal is the same, but the data they have to work with is different (source code vs IL).  As you have already seen, that can lead to different results.

Comment: In my question above the code was stripped down a little bit for illustrative purposes. I tested some more and found out that when I assign a fixed string to "errorText" in both places as in [string errorText = "Some fixed string";] I get the compiler warning (CS0219). As soon as I change this to something a little more complex as in [string errorText = string.Format( "Some variable: {0}", "abc" );] the compiler warning disappears and only the code analysis warning is issued (if code analysis is actually run). I do not understand this behaviour.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger I was just looking at this and noticed there's a note on the [CA1804 information article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1804?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) stating _"The compiler generates this warning only when the variable value is a compile-time constant. Assigning a non-constant expression or method result to a local variable makes it easier to observe those expressions in the debugger. It also makes the result reachable, preventing garbage collection while that variable is reachable."_